# How Do I Properly Ground my Arduino Leonardo using Capacitive Sensor?

Tags: arduino-leonardo

Hi we are using Arduino Leonardo with some electric paint and [Capacitive Sensor Libraries](http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/CapacitiveSensor?from=Main.CapSense). We have a lot of variance in our Serial output from our sensors, we believe if we grounded the Arduino we would have more concrete values.

On the Capacitive Sensor doc, it reveals to use a small capacitor to put on one of the pins. More details!
Another guide somewhere says to wrap the Arduino in plastic and tin foil. These are vague, and we have not landed success when we tried.

Has anyone had success grounding Arduino Leo? Thank you.

Comment: Can you please link the datasheet of the sensor? Thanks!

Comment: @AnnonomusPenguin - the sensor is typically homemade, just some "plates" or in this case it seems areas of conductive paint.  There's an edit in the queue to add a link to http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/CapacitiveSensor?from=Main.CapSense

Answer (score 3):

The documentation for that library is recommending that you place a 100 pF capacitor between the sense pin and ground.

However, I personally suspect you will get the best results when the user's presence affects at small mutual capacitance between a sense surface and a ground surface.

One idea could be to have a large ground plane, and on it a smaller insulated "sense" plate.

Another could be to run two parallel traces in a spiral filling a large area

Do take care to secure you wires - they are part of your sensor too, and if they move relative to each other they will alter the baseline.  Any other mobile cables in the vicinity can have the same effect, especially if they contain a ground that can exhibit capacitance to the sense node.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to ground an Arduino is to attach the ground pin, found on the power header, to a grounded surface, like a metal pipe. As for the capacitor you mentioned, that is called a smoothing capacitor. It is a small capacitor, about 1microfarad, and goes between the supply of the sensor and the ground line.

Comment: Actually, no - the recommendation is for an approximately 100 pF cap *across* the sensor surface (surfaces?).  You are speaking instead of a power supply capacitor, but there isn't really any applicable place to add that except on the Arduino board itself, which would normally be well bypassed.

Answer (score -1):

It might help if you follow the diagram for connecting a button, that way the value of the capacitor sensor wont fluctuate...

*Photo from http://arduino.cc/en/tutorial/button*

[image]

Comment: Huh?  Yes, you could use a button as an input sensor instead of cap sense.  Or you could use a button to trigger a *calibration routine* but it's very clear how you meant this to answer the question?